# IOS Compare two array and get Result

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have below JSON Format:

```
 {
  "Get_your_story_answer": [
    {
      "st_id": "19",
      "story_title": "Newone",
      "user_fb_id": "1649424812005217",
      "winner_fb_id": "1685417121693688",
      "winner_fb_id2": "",
      "winner_fb_id3": "",
      "story": "\ud83d\ude33\ud83d\ude25\ud83d\ude14\ud83d\ude0c",
      "status": "1",
      "s_created_date": "2016-01-18 23:06:05",
      "reply_answer": [
        {
          "l_id": "42",
          "story_id": "19",
          "user_fb_id": "1649424812005217",
          "selected_user_fb_id": "1685417121693688",
          "answer": "hahaha",
          "l_rating": "0",
          "status": "1",
          "l_created_date": "2016-01-18 23:10:51",
          "l_new_created_date": "2016-01-19 11:40:51",
          "winner": "1",
          "answer_user_id": "3",
          "answer_fb_id": "1685417121693688",
          "answer_user_name": "Kin Patty"
        },
        {
          "l_id": "43",
          "story_id": "19",
          "user_fb_id": "1649424812005217",
          "selected_user_fb_id": "1498304680499454",
          "answer": "",
          "l_rating": "0",
          "status": "1",
          "l_created_date": "2016-01-18 23:06:05",
          "l_new_created_date": "2016-01-19 11:36:05",
          "winner": "0",
          "answer_user_id": "10",
          "answer_fb_id": "1498304680499454",
          "answer_user_name": "John Kingman"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "1",
  "msg": "Get data"
}
```

Now I have to get Winner id

**for Example** `"winner_fb_id"` from  `[Get_your_story_answer]` and compare it with `[reply_answer]`.

If `[reply_answer]` contain `"winner_fb_id"` then I have to take only that name as winner . 
Like in my Example , **"Kin Patty"**

I have tried this ,

//_getwind is mutable array

```
  _getwinnerid =[NSMutableArray new];
 _getwinnerid=[[_dataDictionary  valueForKey:@"Get_your_story_answer"]valueForKey:@"winner_fb_id"];
```

Here is _getwinnerid output

> <__NSArrayI 0x7ffb5a57c7b0>(
>   1685417121693688

```
   NSArray *replaydata=[[_dataDictionary  valueForKey:@"Get_your_story_answer"]valueForKey:@"reply_answer"];
```

Here is Replay Data Result

[image]

```
if (![replaydata containsObject:_getwinnerid]) {
    NSLog(@"data");
}
```

**Note:-** Winner Id will be multiple. so, I have to compare 2 or more winner id and then take name from replay data response. And then I have to set name of winner in UITableview.

Comment: That's more a requirements specification than it is a question.  What problem do you have when you try to do it?

Comment: I don't know how to get the final result with comparing winner_fb_id and  selected_user_fb_id. and getting name of that particular winner.

Comment: Total how many winners you can have ?

Comment: @PankajTeckchandani its not a static. it,s come from webservice. that might 2 or 3. or etc,.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Qq896NQs clearly not optimized and not clean, but you may get the idea (I showed each step)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have filtered array using the answer as said by [**larme**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1801544/larme) Thank you.

```
 NSError *errorJSON = nil;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&errorJSON];
    if (!errorJSON)
    {
        NSDictionary *storyAnwser = [json[@"Get_your_story_answer"] firstObject];

        NSArray *allAnswersKeys = [storyAnwser allKeys];
        NSArray *allWinnersKeys = [allAnswersKeys filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSString *  _Nonnull evaluatedObject, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nullable bindings) {
            return [evaluatedObject hasPrefix:@"winner_fb_id"];
        }]];
        NSLog(@"AllWinnersKeys: %@", allWinnersKeys);
        NSArray *allWinnersIds = [storyAnwser objectsForKeys:allWinnersKeys notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];
        NSLog(@"AllWinnersIds: %@", allWinnersIds);

        NSArray *allAnswers = storyAnwser[@"reply_answer"];
        NSLog(@"AllAnswers: %@", allAnswers);
        NSArray *allWinners = [allAnswers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"answer_fb_id IN %@", allWinnersIds]];
        NSLog(@"allWinners: %@", allWinners);
        NSArray *allWinersNames = [allWinners valueForKey:@"answer_user_name"];
        NSLog(@"AllWinnersNames: %@", allWinersNames);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error JSON: %@", errorJSON);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `Get_your_story_answer` is an array, the requested data is in the first item of the array

```
NSDictionary *getYourStoryAnswer = _dataDictionary[@"Get_your_story_answer"][0];
```

Now get the winner ID and the array of answers

```
NSString *winnerID = getYourStoryAnswer[@"winner_fb_id"];
NSArray *answers = getYourStoryAnswer[@"reply_answer"];
```

Then enumerate the answers array (there are other solutions using blocks etc.)

```
for (NSDictionary *answer in answers) {
   if ([answer[@"answer_fb_id"] isEqualToString: winnerID]) {
     NSLog(@"%@", answer[@"answer_user_name"]);
     break;
   }
}
```

PS: **Never** use `valueForKey` to get *one* value for a key from a collection type unless you really need (and mean) the KVC method. The designated method is `objectForKey` or key subscription like above. `valueForKey` applied to an array returns always an array which is normally not intended.

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to get **total winner count** from server.
like this.

**int winnerCount = 3;  //[Get_your_story_answer valueForKey:@"winner_count"];**

Hopefully you have a fixed pattern **key** for winners like **winner_fb_id**, **winner_fb_id1**, **winner_fb_id2** etc.

This will give you the desired result of winners name in array.

```
id response;  // your response here

NSArray *array =  [response objectForKey:@"Get_your_story_answer"];
NSDictionary *Get_your_story_answer = array[0];

NSMutableArray *winnersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

int winnerCount = 3;  //[Get_your_story_answer valueForKey:@"winner_count"];

for (int i = 0; i< winnerCount; i++) {

    NSString *winnerId = nil;

    if(i != 0){
        winnerId = [Get_your_story_answer valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"winner_fb_id%d",i]];
    }
    else{
       winnerId= [Get_your_story_answer valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"winner_fb_id"]];
    }

    if(winnerId)
    {
        [winnersArray addObject:winnerId];
    }
}

__block NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *replyAnswers = [Get_your_story_answer objectForKey:@"reply_answer"];

[replyAnswers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    NSString *answer_fb_id = [obj valueForKey:@"answer_fb_id"];

    [winnersArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ^(NSString * winnerId, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        if([winnerId isEqualToString:answer_fb_id]){

            // get name of winner
            [resultArray addObject:[obj valueForKey:@"answer_user_name"]];
        }

    }];
}];

// Your name of wiiners are in resultArray.
```